# Convert Cron syntax to UTC format

Tags: ruby, cron

I have cron data that I need to convert to UTC format

I have a three variables that represent cron data such as:

```
hour_start
week
weekday
```

These values will be used to schedule a cron job to run a script. Later I realized that I need to make a REST call and pass a parameter formatted in UTC format.

How can I use ruby to convert the above values into a datetime value in UTC format?

Example values:

hour_start : 2 
   week : 2 
   weekday : 1

The above should create a value in UTC format like `2017-07-03 02:00:00`

Monday on the second week of July at 2 am.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what have you already tried and what exact problem you met while writing the code. Also where July came from? Is it the current month?

Comment: I don't even know where to begin with this one. I know the CAL function in bash and some parsing around that might be me where I need to go but I have to do this in Ruby which I am not sure how to convert a week into a date.

Comment: @mudasobwa I flagged you for not constructive as you are not being helpful whatsoever, and downright rude at that.

Comment: You might check how many questions I answered being very constructive. The only condition the question should meet is to follow this site rules and not to be “hey, code for me for free, while I am taking a bath here.”

Comment: Notice how I am not asking for an algorithm, "How can I use ruby to convert the above values into a datetime value in UTC format?". A datetime function or class would be a perfectly acceptable answer. Taking some time to read what is being asked instead of immediately firing off would be beneficial for everyone involved.

Comment: @jacksonecac My understanding is you pass current UTC time and get next occurrence for a cron expression. If so then try this ruby library https://github.com/siebertm/parse-cron "parses cron expressions and calculates the next occurence after a given date"

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs are not specified to run at a particular date, but are instead specified to run at recurring times. If you want to convert to a format like `2017-07-03 02:00:00`, then you need to specify which of these times to convert from.

As derloopkat mentioned, the parse-cron Gem should do what you want: https://github.com/siebertm/parse-cron

It allows passing in a Time object (as one might get from `Time.now`) to either a `next` or `last` method to get the first run time after or before the specified time, respectively.

Comment: Hi good job, on your first answer. Maybe you could improve it by relying less on the link and adding and example using the Gem directly here.